# Google Cloud Standard App Engine 404 Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404, gcloud, google-app-engine-standard

I have a project set up on Google Cloud App Engine Standard as a Flask web app and when I deploy it and access the website, it always returns a 404.
I have tested the deployment locally and it works fine. The logs show no error.
This is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: python39

entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT -w 2 main:app

error_handlers:
  - file: error.html

handlers:
  # This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
  # directory.

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

  # This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
  # required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
  # the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

When I run "gcloud app logs tail -s default" and access the link, I get these logs:

```
2024-02-02 01:40:44 default[20240127t133812]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200
2024-02-02 01:40:44 default[20240127t133812]  [2024-02-02 01:40:44 +0000] [11] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
2024-02-02 01:40:44 default[20240127t133812]  [2024-02-02 01:40:44 +0000] [11] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (11)
2024-02-02 01:40:44 default[20240127t133812]  [2024-02-02 01:40:44 +0000] [11] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
2024-02-02 01:40:44 default[20240127t133812]  [2024-02-02 01:40:44 +0000] [18] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18
2024-02-02 01:40:44 default[20240127t133812]  [2024-02-02 01:40:44 +0000] [21] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21
2024-02-02 01:40:44 default[20240127t133812]  [2024-02-02 01:40:44 +0000] [22] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22
2024-02-02 01:40:44 default[20240127t133812]  [2024-02-02 01:40:44 +0000] [23] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23
2024-02-02 01:40:45 default[20240127t133812]  "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200
2024-02-02 01:40:45 default[20240127t133812]  "GET /static/script.js HTTP/1.1" 200
2024-02-02 01:40:45 default[20240127t133812]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404
2024-02-02 01:42:03 default[20240127t133812]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200
```

This is my main.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
from query_firestore import query
from google.cloud import firestore

@app.route('/')
def index():
    locations = list_locations()
    return render_template('index.html', locations=list(locations))
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```

I don't have /static/style.css or /static/script.js in my directory. They're named static/main.css and static/main.js. I run the deploy command in the right directory and specify the app.yaml but I am still receiving this error.